# Handling form data from javascript function

Tags: php, javascript

I have a form with an ID of 'manage_campaigns'.

I'm trying to call a function and send the form data to a javascript function by using this for the submit button, onclick:

```
javascript:updateAffiliateCampaigns(this);
```

This is the javascript function I have so far:

```
function updateAffiliateCampaigns(oForm) {}
```

I really only have a checkbox list of campaign id's that are being used in the form.
How would I pass which items are checked to the function, and then how would I handle the data in the javascript function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use jquery (http://jsfiddle.net/bkAMR/)

```
$('#manage_campaigns').submit(function(){
    var formData = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        data: formData,
        success: function(data) {
             // I got Donut
            alert(data);
        },
    });
    return false;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, we've got a few things to cover before getting to your actual question

1. The `javascript:` pseudo-protocol is only useful in `href` attributes of anchor elements
2. When using `this` inside an event attribute (like `onclick`) it always refers to the element itself.  So if you put that on a submit button like so `<input type="submit" onclick="updateAffiliateCampaigns(this)"` then `this` will not reference the form, but the submit button itself
3. But that's OK because all form element DOM nodes have a `form` property that references their containing form node.
4. Submit buttons try to submit the form regardless of any javascript execution *unless* you use javascript to cancel the default action, which in this example is achieved by returning `false` to the event attribute

Now that we've covered that...

DOM `form` objects have a property called `elements`, which itself has properties representing the form element's names.

So with this as our example form

```
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" name="campaign" value="1" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="campaign" value="2" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="campaign" value="3" />

  <input type="submit" value="go" onclick="return updateAffiliateCampaigns( this.form );" />
</form>
```

You might then write your function like so

```
function updateAffiliateCampaigns( oForm )
{
  console.log(  );
  var campaign = oForm.elements.campaign;
  var checked  = [];

  for ( var i = 0, l = campaign.length; i < l; i++ )
  {
    if ( campaign[i].checked )
    {
      checked.push( campaign[i].value )
    }
  }

  // The variable "checked" now contains the values of
  // all checked items

  return false;
}
```

Now is the part where I tell you that knowing this stuff is good, but you're also doing it The Hard Way.  JavaScript libraries like jQuery and YUI have made doing tasks like this much, much simpler.